# I want total count of found record

Tags: sql, subquery

```
    Select (RowNo),
*,
(Select TOP 1 Name From TourImages Where TourImages.TourID = T.ID Order By T.ID Desc)
as TourImageName
FROM  (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Tours.MinPrice Asc) s RowNo  
From Tours Where (AgentID = 10) AND (MinPrice > 1) AND (MinPrice < 99999) 
AND (IsActive =1) AND (IsDeleted=0) AND (IsSync=1)) as T Where T.RowNo > 0
```

I want count of these found records can I get max row number in this query ?

Comment: Pls ask the question clearly. it seems max(rownumber),count(*) you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as (Select (RowNo)RowNo,
*,
(Select TOP 1 Name From TourImages Where TourImages.TourID = T.ID Order By T.ID Desc)
as TourImageName
FROM  (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Tours.MinPrice Asc) s RowNo  
From Tours Where (AgentID = 10) AND (MinPrice > 1) AND (MinPrice < 99999) 
AND (IsActive =1) AND (IsDeleted=0) AND (IsSync=1)) as T Where T.RowNo > 0)
select max(RowNo),count(*) from cte
```

Answer (score -1):

The COUNT(*) function returns the number of records in a table:

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name;